# Inconsistent XPATH query results

Tags: c#, xpath, xml-namespaces

I'm in the process of running a conversion process to update some of our xml files. Here's a sample file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Jobs xmlns="urn:mynamespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Job name="Job1">
    <Category>Maintenance</Category>
    <Description>Purge records</Description>
    <Steps>
      <TSql name="Start Job" database="IADS">
        <CommandText>Exec StoredProcedureName</CommandText>
        <OnSuccess action="GotoNextStep" />
        <Retries>0</Retries>
        <OnFailure action="QuitFailure" />
        <OutputFile />
      </TSql>
      <TSql name="Start LoadRequestManagementReportTables" database="msdb">
        <CommandText>exec sp_start_job @job_name = 'Load Request Management Report Tables'</CommandText>
        <OnSuccess action="QuitSuccess" />
        <Retries waitInMinutes="0">0</Retries>
        <OnFailure action="QuitFailure" />
        <OutputFile />
      </TSql>
    </Steps>
    <Schedules>
      <Schedule>
        <Weekly name="Every Sunday at 7:00 AM" enabled="false">
          <BeginDate>2008-11-01</BeginDate>
          <RunTimes>
            <Once>07:00</Once>
          </RunTimes>
          <DaysOfWeek>Sunday</DaysOfWeek>
        </Weekly>
      </Schedule>
      <Schedule>
        <OneTime name="OneTime" enabled="false" rundate="2011-01-12T03:00:00" />
      </Schedule>
    </Schedules>
    <Notifications>
      <EventLog on="Failure" />
    </Notifications>
  </Job>
</Jobs>
```

Now, I'm trying to rename the first step in each of the files that I process to convert it from a TSql step to a CmdExec step. Therefore, I wrote my own "RenameNode" method to do this conversion and copy all attributes and nodes to the newly-named node.

Here's the RenameNode method:

```
private static void RenameNode(XmlNode node, string namespaceURI, string newName)
{
    if (node.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element)
        return;

    XmlElement oldElement = (XmlElement)node;
    XmlElement newElement = node.OwnerDocument.CreateElement(newName, namespaceURI);

    while (oldElement.HasAttributes)
        newElement.SetAttributeNode(oldElement.RemoveAttributeNode(oldElement.Attributes[0]));

    while (oldElement.HasChildNodes)
        newElement.AppendChild(oldElement.FirstChild);

    if (oldElement.ParentNode != null)
        oldElement.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(newElement, oldElement);
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the second query I run is not returning results.

Here's query #1 that I run:

```
XmlNodeList stepNodes = xSchedule.SelectNodes("/mns:Jobs/mns:Job/mns:Steps/mns:TSql", nsm);
```

This works great, returns 2 nodes in my stepNodes variable. I process the "RenameNode" method for stepNodes[0]. Fantastic.

The next thing I want to do is remove the namespace attributes that the "RenameNode" method generates (I'm guessing ya'll will not like that....but that's not the issue). So, in order to do that, I try running a very similar XPATH query that looks like this, but it does NOT return any records:

```
stepNodes = xSchedule.SelectNodes("/mns:Jobs/mns:Job/mns:Steps/mns:CmdExec", nsm);
```

I've tried resetting the namespace manager, I've tried saving the xml file (xSchedule.Save()), tried running the query with and without the namespace prefixes/parameter, etc. It NEVER returns any nodes. Even after doing the rename to the node, after saving the document I can see that it successfully renamed that node (and thus added the xmlns attribute to EVERYTHING in that newly-named node). I even verified that the original query that returns results now returns only 1 node this time.

```
// Let's assume that the very first node is the node that we want to change
        XmlNodeList stepNodes = xSchedule.SelectNodes("/mvst:Jobs/mvst:Job/mvst:Steps/mvst:TSql", nsm);
    if (stepNodes.Count >= 1)
    {
        RenameNode(stepNodes[0], String.Empty, "CmdExec");

        // After renaming the node, let's remove the "database" attribute if it exists
        //XmlElement e = (XmlElement)stepNodes[0];
        //e.RemoveAttribute("database");
        xSchedule.Save(scheduleXmlFile + ".bak");
    }
```

Where am I going wrong with this code?

Comment: How does the intermediate XML look like, or how do you change the nodes?

Comment: Ugh. You prompted me to look at my "RenameNode" method and I noticed I was calling the method by explicitly defining the namespace as String.Empty, instead of the actual value. Switching that fixed my query. I'll update the original question with the rename method if anyone is curious....

Comment: Well, you might have found the problem then. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to pass the namespace information to the RenameNode method.

```
RenameNode(stepNodes[0], "urn:mynamespace", "CmdExec");
```